# Statistics 'has' or 'have' applications?

Tags: grammar

which is correct:

Statistics have applications in almost every field of science and business

Statistics has applications in almost every field of science and business

I thought has should accompany third person singular object (here, Statistics). But online grammar check tells me 'have' should be used.

Can someone throw some light on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

On the one hand, if you are using the word "statistics" to refer to numerous statistical data, then it would be followed by a verb conjugated in the plural number (i.e., "have").

For example,

> The statistics have not provided us with the results we expected.

On the other hand, if you are using the word "statistics" as the name of a subject or field of study, then it would be followed by a verb conjugated in the singular number (i.e., "has").

For example,

> Statistics has never been an easy class for me.

In your example, the word "statistics" refers to a field of study, and therefore, the proper verb would be "has," as in:

> Statistics has applications in almost every field of science and business.